# Linking external resources to Neo4j nodes

Tags: neo4j

I can give the url as a property to a node in Neo4j. Is there a way through which on click of the property/node,Neo4j can open that URL?

Or is there any way through which I can link external resources to Neo4j nodes?

Answer (score 0):

If you store a URI in a node, it's up to your app to determine what to do with it (such as following the link). Neo4j is not going to reach out to external resources for you.

Not sure exactly what you mean by

> link external resources to Neo4j nodes

If you're implying that something external to Neo4j can have a link (pointer, URI, etc.) to a Neo4j node, then no: This is again the domain of your app to provide some type of linkage (via api or any other technique). Just like you cannot have a direct link into a row of a relational database. Not only are you exposing data directly, this would imply bypassing any business rules, security, etc.

Answer (score 0):

### It might be too late to answer but still I would like to mention it here.
**Simplest solution would be to just add your url/hyperlink as a property to the node. Neo4j Browser, Bloom, Graph X(Kineviz) support hyperlinks and redirect you to the corresponding website when you click on the url/hyperlink.**

Example: I have a node called studies. I am adding hyperlink based on the id. Note that the hyperlink will be different for nodes with different nct_id.
CQL :

match( n:studies)
set n.link= case when n.nct_id =null then null else ('https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/'+n.nct_id) end